# Macro to automatically find duplicates in a column, export to them a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I'm working on a spreadsheet that would automatically find duplicate invoices/payments. I have put in a conditional formatting where it would automatically highlight duplicate entries in one column.

I'm looking for a macro that would help me to the following:

1. Move all the duplicate entries to another worksheet for my review
2. Delete the duplicate entries on the new worksheet so I can calculate via Autosum

I'm new to using Excel and I am very eager to learn. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sassa. And best to you on your learning curve. While you have listed requirements for what you need in your question, you haven't actually posted any attempts to try the code. This site works best if you post where you are stuck in your development attempts. Then we come along and try to get you past your stuck points! That said, if you are really, really new and have never worked with VBA before, I suggest using the macro recorder to get some beginning steps.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I have tried recording a macro but it only seem to work when I have the same range of cells. Obviously, not all my data would always be on the same range, some may be lesser or more.

Comment: what i do is have an autosum on the first worksheet, then I manually copy the range of cells which I need to review on to another worksheet, auto-filter by color, then sort to manually review that there are only two duplicates per payment. Afterwhich i use the Remove duplicates function on the Data Tab (I use excel 2007). If this task can be automated, that would be superb!

Comment: Yes, the macro recorder is great to get started, but quickly learned a valuable lesson, it records `EXACTLY` what you do, with no flexibility, which is what you generally need in code. That said, it gave you a start on some syntax and concepts. But you need more, which is why you are here! That said, your process can be automated. The best way is step-by-step, building each component you need. The best way to get help here is to post the code you have and tell us what is not working for you. Then we can help more easily to fix your code, and also you will learn to code faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do a general Duplicate Search,

Then Color all Duplicates

Selects all cells with that color and copy and paste to different sheet.